# Why the use of getch() shows error?

Tags: c

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}   *start=NULL;

void create()
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        struct node *new_node,*current;

        new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        printf("\nEnter the data : ");
        scanf("%d",&new_node->data);
        new_node->next = NULL;

        if(start == NULL)
        {
            start = new_node;
            current = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            current->next = new_node;
            current = new_node;
        }

        printf("nDo you want to creat another : ");
        ch = getch();
    } while(ch!='n');
}
```

This is the part of the code which contains `getch()`

When I try to run this code in an online compiler I am getting this error:
undefined reference to `getch`
collect2: error: 1d returned 1 exit status

How to solve this problem?...Please help

Answer (score 10):

There is no `getch` function in the *standard* C library, it only exist in Windows, and because it's not a standard function its real name is [`_getch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) (note the leading underscore). Judging by the error message your online compiler uses GCC, and most likely in a Linux environment, so no `getch` (or `_getch`)  function.

If you want to be portable use [`fgetc` or `getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) instead, or [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) (but note that those functions returns an `int`).

Comment: Even more, there's a `getch()` function in the `ncurses` library that does the same effect, but it's incorrect to call `ncurses` without initializing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a getch in linux, but in a library

```
#include <ncurses/curses.h>
```

See http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch for more detail. If the online compiler works under linux, and get the ncurses library, this will be work !

Comment: So, what other suitable command can I use in place of getch() in this program while using linux?

Comment: Yeah sure, if there is ncurses library on your compiler, getch return an int, so you could try
int key;
key = getch();
and key will be an int representing an ascii character.
You could use aswell the function : keypad(stdscr, TRUE); to allow every macro of curses.h !

Comment: It's incorrect to call curses libraries without initializing it.... and it loads the program with an unnecessary dependency that is nosense.  It's better to make a miniimplementation using `termios` ioctls.

Comment: @LuisColorado The problem with using termios is that you exchange one non-standard feature (the Windows `_getch` function) for another (the POSIX termios system).

Comment: Not... you are adding a stub implementation of something missing in other architecture.  I'm not proposing using even the same name.... I think the use of `getch` is some ancient using from TurboC programs.  But using the `ncurses` implementation is not a good idea, as has been suggested some times.

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem.
But _getche() instead of getch() had solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` might solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, please elaborate on why you think `getchar()` will solve the authors problem, and provide references so this answer is more beneficial

Comment: It's mentioned in the top answer anyway, so this answer is essentially a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It is contained in the `conio.h` library. So I think you should only add this line:

```
#include<conio.h>
```

Note: `conio.h` is platform-specific.